# SQL query to get output from referring data in single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables and the expected result like this:

This is the example table:

[image]

This is the expected output from the table:

[image: test]

To get the result I must refer the `id` and `parentid` from table2.

How to write a SQL query based on the pictures above?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Can you explain you get `City 3` in the expected output when it isn't in the supplied input?

Comment: @HABO Sorry my mistake it should be City C, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `table1` to 2 copies of `table2`, the first is directly linked to the `id` of `table1` and the 2nd is linked to the `parentid` of `table2`.
Then join to `table3`.

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.city
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 c ON c.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN table2 p ON p.id = c.parentid
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = p.parentid
```